# How to separate multiple data present in a single column and put it into different sets of columns?

Tags: excel, csv, data-analysis

I have a set of data as shown in the image below:

[image: Data logged from a device]

As you can see, in the column C, I have Irms-E1 and Uthd repeated multiple number of times along with their corresponding value below them. My question is how do I separate them into two distinct colums as Irms-E1 into one column and Uthd into another column?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your 1st "Irms-E1" is located at C4. You may put this formulas in H5 & I5, then drag downwards.

```
H5  ---> =IF(C4="Irms-E1",C5,"")
I5  ---> =IF(C4="Uthd",C5,"")
```

Hope it helps. (: